# Node-RED: uibuilder node: Update html element (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, node-red

I am using the ["uibuilder"](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-uibuilder) node in Node-RED to create a floorplan, [based on this one](https://flows.nodered.org/flow/02eb3716157db586f3f5b8a85c241009), where the light of a bulb should change the color based on the input (grey, red or green).

In the example the color is changed with true or false and works fine, but as i need three different colors, i have to get another solution or is it possible to use "undefined" as a third option?

I have no idea how or where i could build in a switch statement there.
Can someone lead me in the right direction?

My code snippets:

html-file:

```html
    <script type="text/x-template" id="bulb-template">
        <svg @click="doClick" :style="ciconstyle" :height="height" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <defs>
                <filter id="shadow">
                    <feDropShadow dx="1" dy="1" stdDeviation="5" flood-opacity="50%" />
                </filter>
                <filter id="glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                        x="-40%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
                    <!-- blur the text at different levels-->
                    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur5"/>
                    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur10"/>
                    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" result="blur20"/>
                    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="30" result="blur30"/>
                    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50" result="blur50"/>
                    <!-- merge all the blurs except for the first one -->
                    <feMerge result="blur-merged">
                        <feMergeNode in="blur10"/>
                        <feMergeNode in="blur20"/>
                        <feMergeNode in="blur30"/>
                        <feMergeNode in="blur50"/>
                    </feMerge>
                    <!-- recolour the merged blurs red-->
                    <feColorMatrix result="red-blur" in="blur-merged" type="matrix"
                                    values="1 0 0 0 0
                                            0 0.06 0 0 0
                                            0 0 0.44 0 0
                                            0 0 0 1 0" />
                    <feMerge>
                        <!--<feMergeNode in="red-blur"/>        largest blurs coloured red -->
                        <feMergeNode in="blur-merged"/>
                        <feMergeNode in="blur5"/>          <!-- smallest blur left white -->
                        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  <!-- original -->
                    </feMerge>
                </filter>
                <slot name="filter"></slot>
            </defs>
            <title>{{title}}</title>
            <slot name="icon"><path :fill="cfillcolor" d="M511.549861 803.293331H408.419043a73.232959 73.232959 0 0 1-67.1862-41.991375 59.795719 59.795719 0 0 1-6.71862-30.569722 207.60536 207.60536 0 0 0-33.593101-113.88061 196.519637 196.519637 0 0 0-27.882273-33.5931A463.248853 463.248853 0 0 1 217.274302 504.314738a399.086031 399.086031 0 0 1-36.95241-75.248544 242.542184 242.542184 0 0 1-15.116895-77.264131 349.032312 349.032312 0 0 1 8.062344-84.990544 314.76735 314.76735 0 0 1 51.733375-114.888403A367.172586 367.172586 0 0 1 361.724634 34.011334 327.532728 327.532728 0 0 1 433.949799 8.144647 369.524103 369.524103 0 0 1 528.682342 0.418234a333.579486 333.579486 0 0 1 126.310057 29.225997 326.860866 326.860866 0 0 1 70.881442 44.678824A382.625412 382.625412 0 0 1 808.848799 168.383736a314.095488 314.095488 0 0 1 41.991375 105.146403 312.751764 312.751764 0 0 1 6.382689 92.045095 275.799353 275.799353 0 0 1-20.15586 76.256338 449.139751 449.139751 0 0 1-61.139443 107.16199 497.513815 497.513815 0 0 1-33.5931 39.639858 160.575019 160.575019 0 0 0-31.241583 48.038134 215.331773 215.331773 0 0 0-18.812136 55.428615c-1.679655 11.757585 0 23.179239-2.687448 33.5931a171.660742 171.660742 0 0 1-3.695241 25.194826 69.873649 69.873649 0 0 1-33.593101 40.647651 74.576683 74.576683 0 0 1-39.639858 10.07793zM490.050277 88.768088c-11.085723 0-22.171446 2.351517-33.5931 4.031172a210.96467 210.96467 0 0 0-74.240752 26.538549 244.221839 244.221839 0 0 0-55.428616 44.342893 222.386324 222.386324 0 0 0-43.335099 63.82689 230.784599 230.784599 0 0 0-19.483998 94.732543 28.218204 28.218204 0 0 0 33.5931 28.890066 28.890066 28.890066 0 0 0 22.171446-26.202618v-13.773171a167.965501 167.965501 0 0 1 9.406068-49.045927 184.762052 184.762052 0 0 1 64.834684-83.98275 167.965501 167.965501 0 0 1 93.72475-33.593101 142.770676 142.770676 0 0 0 18.140274 0 23.851101 23.851101 0 0 0 19.148067-15.452826 33.5931 33.5931 0 0 0 0-19.483998 23.51517 23.51517 0 0 0-20.491791-18.140274 122.950747 122.950747 0 0 0-15.116895 0zM647.601917 943.040628a15.788757 15.788757 0 0 1-13.773171 15.116895H400.356699a17.468412 17.468412 0 0 1-16.460619-8.734206 18.812136 18.812136 0 0 1 0-20.15586 16.124688 16.124688 0 0 1 16.460619-4.703034h227.089358a19.148067 19.148067 0 0 1 19.148067 20.827722zM405.731595 899.369598a18.140274 18.140274 0 0 1-16.460619-12.765378 17.804343 17.804343 0 0 1 15.452826-23.851101H635.508401a18.812136 18.812136 0 0 1 17.804343 13.773171 19.819929 19.819929 0 0 1-10.749792 21.499584 24.187032 24.187032 0 0 1-8.734206 0H423.535938zM437.64504 1022.992207a17.132481 17.132481 0 0 1-15.452826-9.406068 18.140274 18.140274 0 0 1 15.116895-26.202618h139.411367a19.819929 19.819929 0 0 1 19.483998 17.804343 16.124688 16.124688 0 0 1-8.734206 15.788757 19.148067 19.148067 0 0 1-9.741999 3.023379H442.348074z" /></slot>
            <slot name="default"></slot>
        </svg>
    </script>

    <bulb id="a" :color="isona ? 'green' : 'red'" :glow="isona" :clickable="true" style="left: 33%; top: 24%" @bulbclicked="myClick" title="A: clicked"></bulb>
    <bulb id="b" :ison="isonb" :clickable="true"  style="left: 25%; top: 65%" @bulbclicked="myClick" title="B"></bulb>
```

js-file:

```js
        template: '#bulb-template',
        props: {
            color: {
               type: String,
               required: false,
               default: 'grey',
            },
            ...

            ison: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: false,
                default: false,
            },
    ...

    var app1 = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            isonb: false,
            isona: false,
            isonc: false,
            isond: false,
        },
        // Get things started
        mounted: function(){

            /** **REQUIRED** Start uibuilder comms with Node-RED */
            uibuilder.start()

        // msg is updated when a standard msg is received from Node-RED
            uibuilder.onChange('msg', function(msg){

                if ( msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('A') ) {
                    app1.isona = msg.payload.A
                }
                if ( msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('B') ) {
                    app1.isonb = msg.payload.B
                }
                if ( msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('C') ) {
                    app1.isonc = msg.payload.C
                }
                if ( msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('D') ) {
                    app1.isond = msg.payload.D
                }
            })
        } // --- End of mounted hook --- //
    }) // --- End of app1 --- //
```

Comment: If you can parse the color directly into your 'bulb' component then it should be, due the reactivity of vue, possible to just change it input of :color=... to a variable which changes in your js.
could you share the html of your bulb component?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat thx for your reply. I added the html you asked for.